# SharePoint Online stop permissions inheritance on the list via PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

As the question basically says, is there a way to stop permissions inheritance on a list or a library via PowerShell?

Moreover there is a way to change user or group permissions on this list/library?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SharePoint 2013/Online [supports a sets of APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164060.aspx), CSOM or REST APIs could be consumed in PowerShell for that purpose.

### How to stop permissions inheritance for a List in SharePoint Online

> Prerequisites: [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

The example below shows how to assign unique permissions for a list using CSOM API in PowerShell:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")


Function Get-ClientContext([string]$Url,[string]$UserName,[string]$Password)
{
    $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
    $context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
    return $context
}


Function List-BreakInheritance([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context,[string]$ListTitle)
{
    $list = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListTitle)
    $list.BreakRoleInheritance($true, $false)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
}


$UserName = "jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the password"    
$Url = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/"

$context = Get-ClientContext -Url $Url -UserName $UserName -Password $Password
List-BreakInheritance -Context $context -ListTitle "Tasks"
$context.Dispose()
```

> As an alternative, you could also consider to utilize REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this can't be done with PowerShell (yet). You have to use [Office 365 API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/api-catalog) for this action.

Ref: [Index of Windows PowerShell for SharePoint Online cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161364.aspx)

Comment: You could run CSOM from PowerShell also: http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/12/Using-CSOM-in-PowerShell-scripts-with-Office365.html